# What is the difference between 扱う、捌く、 解決する and 処理する

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, usage

These words have similar meanings along the lines of:

"deal with" "take care of" "settle" "manage" "handle" "process" some issue or something

For example what are the nuances of these sentences?

1. 問題をうまく扱う
2. 問題をうまく捌く
3. 問題をうまく解決する
4. 問題をうまく処理する

I have difficulty differentiating the contexts that each are used in and it's meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **扱う**: literally "do something with it while holding it in hands"
- **捌く**: literally "quickly put away / clean up"
- **解決する**: straightforwardly "solve" or "settle"
- **処理する**: "process" or "dispose of"

The last two just mean what those words mean, so the problem is the first two. They each carry specific metaphor when used with abstract things.

扱う puts a focus on careful handling, or the method you take when you handle something.

> 問題をうまく扱う

is thus heard when you take care of it wisely without messing it up or letting it break down etc. In this collocation, 扱う also could be interpreted as "bring up (as a topic)".

捌く suggests efficient or high throughput processing. When you say

> 問題をうまく捌く

it is like you deal with it nimbly, with minimal effort, or arranging people to have it done smoothly etc. Sometimes it even implies triaging (i.e. you don't cope with every corner of the problem).

Comment: Which one would you use for `to fix the problem we have with someone` ("someone" is the problem)?

Comment: @Alexis As long as when 問題 is used, I think you can mostly use 解決, but the problem is that we often use other words in such situations i.e. 関係を修復する. Do you have a detailed context?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! For example someone making noises at night. 騒音の問題を解決する？

Comment: @Alexis I think I'd most naturally say how exactly I "fixed that problem", or use 対処する (this sound a bit adverse though).

Comment: I see and in more or less keigo? For example someone asking the 不動産 for help? 対処 seems a bit strong. Also thank you for you answer!

Comment: @Alexis Hmm... in that case, I'd say like 夜中に騒音を立てるので**困っている** or ～ので**どうにかして**ほしい and the landowner would say **なんとかして**みる or **言っておく/注意しておく**. Doesn't quite work literally regardless of keigo.

Comment: Of course, I could have suspected it, not direct..Thank you for your clarification!